# Meteor's mongodb insertion failed when storing GeoJSON Objects in field "loc"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm inserting an object `listingItemInjectionObj` in my Meteor app and one of its properties is as follows

```
listingItemInjectionObj.loc = { 
    type: "Point", 
    coordinates: [ lat, lng ] // google api lat(), lng() stored in vars
};
```

however when I insert `Listings.insert(listingItemInjectionObj);` I get the following error `"insert failed: MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16804 location object expected, location array not in correct format"` I'm going based off of [GeoJSON Objects](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/geojson/#point) and I came here after having tried [this SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721742/mongodb-geospatial-index-array-not-in-correct-format).

Answer (score 0):

You've got latitude and longitude in the wrong order in your array. GeoJSON takes long before lat in the coordinates:

```
listingItemInjectionObj.loc = { 
    type: "Point", 
    coordinates: [ lng, lat ]
};
```

Comment: thank you, I tried exactly that, I tried to digg up on error code 16804 and I've got nothing

Comment: have you checked that your `lng` and `lat` are numbers and not strings?

Comment: yes, and I've also used parseInt and the issue still stands. I'm not exactly sure if the version of MongoDB (2.6) I'm using supports GeoJSON?

Comment: yes, it does. weird. I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you show an actual example, with everything filled in? Have you tried to simply insert that same object from the mongo shell?

Comment: oh, and are you sure that it is the `loc` property that is causing the error? what else is in the object?

Comment: here is a repo https://github.com/AnjirHossain/Traverso/blob/master/client/sell/sell.js, I've even resorted to legacy points and the problem still stands.

Comment: well that and some string properties but nothing that could interrupt GeoJSON formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code works:-

Request payload:
{"loc":["-12.62","21.48"]}

Node.js backend:
var lat, lon, loc = req.body.loc;
if(loc && loc instanceof Array && loc.length) {
    lat = parseInt(loc[0], 10) || 0;
    lon = parseInt(loc[1], 10) || 0;
    data['loc'] = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates : [lat, lon]
    };
}
```